# Determining singular locus from fibers of a resolution

Tags: algebraic-geometry, birational-geometry

It is sometimes possible to determine the singular locus of a variety $X$ by looking only at the fibers of a resolution of singularities $\pi : Y \to X$. For instance, if the locus contracted by $\pi$ is of codimension two or greater (a small contraction), then we know that the image of $\pi$ is the singular locus of $X$.

Consider the variety
$$Q := V(x_1 y_1 + x_2 y_2 + x_3 y_3) \subset \mathbb{P}^3 \times \mathbb{P}^3$$

Write $L := [1:0:0:0] \times \mathbb{P}^3$ and $L' := \mathbb{P}^3 \times [1:0:0:0]$.  $Q$ is singular at $P: = ([1:0:0:0],[1:0:0:0]) = L \cap L'$.

Consider the resolutions $\pi : Y \to Q$ and $\pi' : Y' \to Q$ which are the blowings-up of $Q$ at $L$ and $L'$, respectively.  (Let's agree to pretend that we do not know what the singular locus of $Q$ is, and that we've just been handed these resolutions as abstract morphisms with the knowledge that $Y$ and $Y'$ are smooth but no particular information about how they were obtained.)

Because $\pi$ is one-to-one along $L' \setminus P$, we know that $Q$ is smooth there.  Similarly, we can conclude that $Q$ is smooth along $L \setminus P$.  From this alone we can conclude that $Q$ is either smooth or singular at $P$ alone.

**Question**: Is it possible to continue this type of argument and conclude, from information about the fibers of $\pi$ and $\pi'$ alone, that $Q$ is in fact singular at $P$?

Comment: I'm confused by several things in this question. What is your definition of a resolution of singularities? At least what I think of as a resolution of singularities is surjective and an isomorphism on the smooth locus of the base so I don't understand the first paragraph. Also your $Q$ is a smooth variety. Do you mean the cone over $Q$ in which case you are working with a threefold not a surface?

Comment: Also assuming you do want the cone over $Q$, I'm confused by "as the preimage of the singular locus in that resolution is a divisor we don't get any information of the type described above..." We do get information about the singular locus. It is exactly the image of the locus where $\pi$ is not an isomorphism, which is always the case with my definition of resolution at least.

Comment: @DoriBejleri: I've fixed the question now; thanks for catching my brain out to lunch.